# How can I change the container type for a class in python?

Tags: python, class, numpy

For example, I would like to store attributes in a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Stick a numpy array on your instance, and put whatever you want inside that.

Comment: That's not completely true.  Numpy has a section in the documentation on how to subclass a numpy array:  http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html -- With that said, composition is usually easier...